# Interface with two different return types unknown till runtime

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

Apologies, if this was already asked before. I'm new to the language and don't really know how to phrase my question properly.
I currently have to rewrite an Application that uses a C# library that is no longer maintained. There is a new API that does the same things but uses a different data structure.
Since I'll have to support both of them, my idea was to create a common interface to access the methods of the chosen API.
I was thinking of doing the following

```
public interface IAPIService<T> {
    List<T> GetEntries(...);
    //...
}
public class API1Service: IAPIService<APIType1> {...};
public class API2Service: IAPIService<APIType2> {...};
```

and in my Main Class using something like

```
IAPIService<?????> api;
if (API1) { api = new API1Service(); }
else { api = new API2Service(); }
```

However, since I have them typed and I don't know until runtime which Type to use I'm stuck.

Comment: Do `APIType1` and `APIType2` have anything in common?

Comment: No, that is the problem. They are only semantically equal, but don't share any code.

Comment: You are leaking implementation detail to the client. If you want to hide which API you are _actually_ using, then the client cannot have any means in telling that. That also means, if there are datastructures specific to the respective APIs, you'll need to abstract/normalize them, too.

Comment: what are the criteria to decide which API is supposed to be used?

Comment: An entry in the config-File or a command line argument should suffice I guess.

Comment: it seems that you need to write a wrapper for the return type. What exactly does it mean: " They are only semantically equal" ?

Answer (score 1):

If old and new APIs have nothing in common outside their purpose, then generics is *not* the right tool for you. You need to *hide* the fact that there *are* two different APIs from clients.

So, what I'd suggest is something like this:

Let's assume old API is `APIv1` and new API is `APIv2`.

```
// This is the CLIENT-Facing Facade (=internal API) which _hides_ the actual impl.
public interface IAPIFacade
{
     MyDataStructure1 DoSomething( MyDataStructure2 input ); 
}

public class APIFacadeImplForAPIv1 : IAPIFacade
{
     private readonly IAPIv1 apiClient;

     MyDataStructure1 DoSomething( MyDataStructure2 input )
     {
           // translate specific datastructures somehow
           ApiV1SpecificDS2 apiInput = Convert<ApiV1SpecificDS2>(input)
           var result = apiClient.DoSomething( apiInput );
           // translate to common datastructure from api - specific
           return Convert<MyDataStructure1>(result);
     }
}
```

Analoguous for APIv2...

```
public class APIFacadeImplForAPIv2 : IAPIFacade // Notice SAME interface!
{
     private readonly IAPIv2 apiClient;

     MyDataStructure1 DoSomething( MyDataStructure2 input )
     {
           // translate specific datastructures somehow
           ApiV2SpecificDS2 apiInput = Convert<ApiV2SpecificDS2>(input)
           var intermediateResult = apiClient.DoSomethingTheOtherWay( apiInput );
           var result = apiClient.InV2IneedTwoCalls(intermediateResult);
           // translate to common datastructure from api - specific
           return Convert<MyDataStructure1>(result);
     }
}
```

Now, in the client you can use DI or a factory or whatever you find to be fit for the task:

```
// ONE interface       vv Factory decides which wrapper to inst. based on config
IAPIFacade apiClient = APIFactory.GetClient(config);
```

Think of it a bit like the Microsoft Logging API. You can "plug in" many different logging frameworks. All they need is a supporting bridge between the MS API and their own. But clients eventually don't care.

Answer (score -1):

You can use factory partern some thing like this

```
private readonly IDictionary<Type, object> _apiService;


public IAPIService<T> GetService<T>() where T : class
        {
            IRepository<T> apiService;
            if (_apiService.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)))
                apiService= _apiService[typeof(T)] as IAPIService<T>;
            else
            {
                apiService= new IAPIService<T>();
                this._apiService.Add(typeof(T), repository);
            }

            return apiService;
        }
```

Comment: That would still give you a strongly typed return value, meaning that client needs to know in advance, which API will be used. Purpose of it all defeated. Generics is not the right solution here.

Comment: That's not an implementation of Unit-of-Work. That's a factory returning different instances of a service

Comment: ^^ * ... different instances of _different_ services.